# How to consume text/plain response with Restlet 2.1 from GWT client?

Tags: java, gwt, rest, restlet-2.0

I have a GWT client that would like to query a RESTful service that returns `text/plain`. I created a proxy interface:

```
public interface ConnectionStatusService extends ClientProxy 
{
    @Get("txt")
    public void getVersion(Result<String> callback);
}
```

But when I'm using the generated proxy class:

`ConnectionStatusService service = GWT.create(ConnectionStatusService.class);`

it sends a request that accepts `Accept application/x-java-serialized-object+gwt` according to Firebug, so the server returns HTTP 406 Not Acceptable of course.. :-( How could I make it accept plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [resty-gwt](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/index.html) to create restfull web services but I'm not accessing it now from GWT client classes. They have documentation where it's documented.

Hope that helps.